# Not understood a line in my .bat file

Tags: batch-file, processbuilder

It is written somewhere in my code

```
process = new ProcessBuilder(actualPath, arguments, startupFilePath).start();
```

where

```
**actualPath**='E:\...build\libs\Mock\StartDriverDelivery.bat'

**arguments**='java -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Xms64m -Xmx96m "-Xbootclasspath/a:$(VUERoot)java\lib\PVTextExtension-1.1.0.jar;$(VUERoot)java\lib\PVTextExtension-1.0.0.jar " vue.exam.driver.init.StartupFileInitializer -Xms64m -Xmx512m' 

**startupPath**='"E:\Code\GITHUB\deliverymanager\build\libs\config\evt\64316e\1.startup"
```

Can someone confirm me if above code statement is calling StartDriverDelivery.bat file ??
If yes, How can i pass "arguments" variable to my bat file ?

My bat file content is :

```
@echo off

SET MyPath=%~dp0
SET JREHome=%MyPath%..\..\..\
IF EXIST %JREHome%..\..\gauge\libs\JRE\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe (
    SET JavaExe=%JREHome%..\..\gauge\libs\
) ELSE (
    SET JavaExe=%JREHome%
)
set CLASSPATH=%JREHome%*
SET JAVA_ARGS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n

SET OP="ExamDelivery"

"%JavaExe%JRE\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw" "-Djava.library.path=%JavaExe%JRE\jre1.8.0_91\bin"  %JAVA_ARGS%  com.vue.exam.deliverymanager.sampleDriver.Main %OP% %*
```

Please someone let me know what last line is doing in bat file ?
...... com.vue.exam.deliverymanager.sampleDriver.Main %OP% %*

And How can i pass "arguments" variable to my bat file followed by sampleDriver.Main class?

Comment: Please someone suggest

Answer (score 0):

The last line is running java.  See the [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).  The last parameter passed to the javaw command is %*, which means your batch file is passing along all of the parameters it received.  It appears that several arguments are being passed to your bat file based on the arguments string and you should be able to add others by appending to that string.